# android room updating Or deleting item when backend modified

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem with the android room

when the data in the backend gets deleted from a Web app 
room doesn't update its data (i want the same data that got remove to be removed from room DB)
how can I achieve this?

```
@Dao
interface RepairDao{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(repairs: List<Repair>)

    @Update
    fun updateAll(repairs: List<Repair>)


    @Query("select * from repairs_tbl")
    fun getRepairs():LiveData<List<Repair>>


   @Query("DELETE FROM repairs_tbl")
   fun clear()
}
```

should i use clear after geting the data ? 
i need the best practice

Answer (score 1):

The exact implementation will depend on your app but.... The simplest approach here would be to clear your database table when you've made a successful api call and are about to insert fresh data.